# ArcMap location queries

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, geoprocessing

I'm new to ArcGIS and am trying to determine sites that meet a series of geographic criteria including: within various distances of certain features, as well as within a distance of one layer **but not within** that layer, and within a distance **or inside** of the last layer.

I'm having trouble figuring out the last two criteria right now without getting too complicated with the geoprocessing tools. So far I've just buffered the layers where I just need to be within a distance of them, and then I intersected these to cut down on potential sites. I tried to use the Select by Location tool after with selection method, "select features from", where target layer = the intersected layer, and using the layer with the bold criteria as the source. I'm not seeing any options for the spatial selection methods that can help me; the closest one seems like, "are within a distance of the source layer feature"

Also, if anyone could tell me why my intersection from buffered layers doesn't have any records in the attribute table even though I can see the different polygons on the map - I was confused on that, too.

Comment: Please edit your question to include details of the settings that you used in the Select by Location tool.

Comment: Can you give some examples of those last two criteria? Do you mean something like "within 50 miles of Country A's border, but not inside Country A" for the second criteria, and "inside Country A or within 50 miles of it" for the third criteria?

Comment: the two criteria are: 1) within 2000ft of or inside of the zone 2) within 2000 ft of but not inside of zone